# Why am I unable to crawl people over SSL / HTTPS?

Tags: people-search, ssl, crawl

If I attempt to perform a crawl of a people content source using a path like sps3://mysites I get an error such as the following:

> The URL of the item could not be resolved. The repository might be unavailable, or the crawler proxy settings are not configured. To configure the crawler proxy settings, use Search Administration page.

No matter what I do I can't seem to get rid of this error as long as I am using HTTPS for my MySites host. If I extend my web app to http://anotherUrl I can crawl people but then the URL for the people results is incorrect.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to change sps3 to sps3s such that the url was sps3s://mysites.

I thought I recalled another protocol but I couldn't find any hint of anything other than STS from the SharePoint 2007 days.

I eventually stumbled upon [this article](http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2011/07/22/troubleshooting-sharepoint-people-search-101/) which provided the answer as well as many other search crawl related issues and their solutions.

After I found this I went back to google to do a reverse lookup and I did find where in the official documentation this was:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh582311.aspx

> In the Path section, in the Path box, type the start address for the User Profile service application in the form sps3://My_Site_host_URL, where My_Site_host_URL is the URL for the Web application where you deployed the My Sites site collection.
>   If the web application where you deployed the My Sites site collection uses Secure Sockets Layer (SSL), then type the start address in the form sps3s://My_Site_host_URL.